# How to plot a scatter graph

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I feel embarrassed to even ask this question. I'm unable to plot a scatter graph based upon the data I have.

My data looks like

```
    A        B        C        D
   Mon      Tues     Weds     Thrs
    2        9        6         9
    8        9        9         8
    5        4        7         3
    6        2        4         4
    2        7        9         5
```

This is a **representation** of how I'd like the chart to be (the image doesn't try to correlate to the demo values in the above table)

[image]

I'm unable to do so. The below shows my effort

[image]

For some reason, it doesn't show Monday and furthermore I can't get the axis correct... I can't get (as per the image above) an Axis with days of the week!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The graph you produce is off the data you have. There is only one "Monday" so all inputs for that day will be above that day. The Scatter Graph you included as your desired result requires sub sections of Monday, maybe an hour value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do what you have been doing, then click **Switch Row/Column** on the chart design ribbon. Then format the X axis to have only full numbers.

[image]

XY scatter charts need numeric data for both axes. You have category data (week days) instead of numbers.

The sample chart in your question is more sophisticated. It looks like there are some kind time aspects for each week day.

This can be done in a XY scatter chart with date/time values on the horizontal (X) axis, but your data source would have to contain X/Y pairs for each data point. Right now it doesn't.

In addition to that you would have to introduce a helper series that plots a zero Y value in select positions on the X axis, then use data labels below these data points to mark out the day names.